# id value needs a default value according to error 1364?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, mysql-error-1364

I want to create two tables. `practice` has a `AUTO_INCREMENT` attachment and is a `PRIMARY KEY`. `continued` has the id entity `continued_id` which exists as a `FOREIGN KEY` that references `practice(user_id)`. Mysql executes the code below fine until line 19, where I receive the 1364 error, stating that `continued_id` has no default value.

I am confused. I thought that `user_id`, which auto_increments, and it being the PK, would have a defining value of 1,2,3... I thought that `continued_id` is equivalent to `user_id`, and therefore its default value is 1? Perhaps I am misunderstanding how PK's and FK's actually work in sql?

Error:

```
20:03:02    INSERT INTO continued(hobby) VALUES("Tennis")   Error Code: 1364. Field 'continued_id' doesn't have a default value 0.000 sec
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE practice(
    user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    user_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    user_real_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE continued(
    continued_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(continued_id)REFERENCES practice(user_id),
    hobby VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO practice(user_name,user_real_name)
VALUES("KittenKing","Henry");
INSERT INTO practice(user_name,user_real_name)
VALUES("DogDictator","Mary");
INSERT INTO practice(user_name,user_real_name)
VALUES("HamsterHam","Denver");

INSERT INTO continued(hobby)
VALUES("Tennis");
INSERT INTO continued(hobby)
VALUES("Hockey");
INSERT INTO continued(hobby)
VALUES("Spear Hunting");

SELECT * FROM practice,continued;
```

Comment: You set "continued_id" to `INT NOT NULL`. That's the expected behavior. Did you mean to add `INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL`?

Comment: That resulted in the desired outcome. Can you explain why I need to write AUTO_INCREMENT twice however? I thought the purpose of a foreign key is to bring over data from one table row to another. If I need to express that ```continued_id``` is AI, the why not do something like ```continued_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,``` instead of ```continued_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, FOREIGN KEY(continued_id)REFERENCES practice(user_id)```?  In other words, what is the point of having this FK if I need to restate that it is a INT that AUTO_INCREMENT's? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inserts into `continued` need to be linked to an entry in `practice`. You can either do that by immediately following the insert into `practice` with an insert into `continued` using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for `continued_id`:

```
INSERT INTO practice (user_name,user_real_name)
VALUES("KittenKing","Henry");
INSERT INTO continued (continued_id, hobby)
VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Tennis')
```

or by referring to the appropriate entry in `practice` using an `INSERT ... SELECT` query:

```
INSERT INTO continued (continued_id, hobby)
SELECT user_id, 'Hockey'
FROM practice 
WHERE user_real_name = 'Mary'
```

or

```
INSERT INTO continued (continued_id, hobby)
SELECT user_id, 'Spear Hunting'
FROM practice 
WHERE user_name = 'HamsterHam'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7888c9fb4f16a13f42ad0331cb217e1b)

Note that you do *not* need to declare `continued_id` as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 1):

your table `continued` has foreign key `continued_id` in table `practice`, so this field is mandatory.

```
INSERT INTO continued(continued_id, hobby)
VALUES(1, "Tennis");
INSERT INTO continued(continued_id, hobby)
VALUES(2, "Hockey");
INSERT INTO continued(continued_id, hobby)
VALUES(3, "Spear Hunting");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` for `continued` needs to be the last inserted id for practice.  Assuming you want one hobby per practice, I would recommend:

```
INSERT INTO practice (user_name, user_real_name)
    VALUES('KittenKing', 'Henry');

INSERT INTO continued (continued_id, hobby)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Tennis');

INSERT INTO practice(user_name, user_real_name)
    VALUES('DogDictator', 'Mary');

INSERT INTO continued (hobby)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Hockey');

INSERT INTO practice(user_name ,user_real_name)
    VALUES('HamsterHam', 'Denver');

INSERT INTO continued (continued_id, hobby)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Spear Hunting');
```

Comment: That resulted in: ```17:38:30 INSERT INTO continued (continued_id, hobby)     VALUES(LAST_INSERTED_ID(), 'Tennis') Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION practice.LAST_INSERTED_ID does not exist 0.000 sec
```